# how can i access jhipster with docker start on mac

Tags: docker, jhipster

how can i access jhipster with docker start on mac

i followed http://www.jhipster.tech/installation/ jh docker install manual and

started successfuly in docker machine,

```
2017-12-10 03:10:50.108  INFO 756 --- [  restartedMain] com.mycompany.myapp.AppApp               :
----------------------------------------------------------

    Application 'app' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:          http://localhost:8081
    External:       http://172.17.0.2:8081
    Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
```

with the chrome : http://172.17.0.2:8081 can't access

my docker-machine ip is :

```
➜  ~ docker-machine ip default

192.168.99.100
```

with the chrome : http://192.168.99.100:8081/ can't access.

in docker machine:

```
jhipster@1d6acc47f610:~/generator-jhipster$ curl http://172.17.0.2:8081
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>JHipster microservice homepage</title>
    <style>
        ::-moz-selection {
            background: #b3d4fc;
            text-shadow: none;
        }
```

it seems that it is the docker-machine's mechanism: how to access the docker-
machine ip

Answer (score 0):

I can see you changed the default port of your application, from `8080` to `8081`.

It depends on how you started the JHipster container, but you need to add the mapping port `8081` to access to it.
Try this, inside the folder of your application:

`docker container run --name jhipster -v ${PWD}:/home/jhipster/app -v ~/.m2:/home/jhipster/.m2 -p 8080:8080 -p 9000:9000 -p 3001:3001 -p 8081:8081 -d -t jhipster/jhipster`